# Unable to read euro symbol(€) and German characters like (ö, ß, ü, ä, Ä) from a .CSV file in java

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, inputstream

Unable to read euro symbol(€) and German characters like (ö, ß, ü, ä, Ä) from a CSV file in java. The point here is that this behaviour is only seen when uploading a CSV file through windows. When we upload the same file from Linux machines we are able to see the Character uploaded successfully. We are using Linux servers which by default uses UTF-8 character set. We also tried to change the character set from UTF-8 to ISO_8859_1, but some character sets are not supported in Linux environment.

**Code Overview:**

The code is basically a Rest Service, which accepts .csv file as multipart form data. Below is the sample code which is used to write the uploaded contents to the file system.

```
// Reading file data using multipart-form/data  
FormDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = multiPart.getField("fileContent");
InputStream fileInputStream = fileDataBodyPart.getValueAs(InputStream.class)

// Writing to a TEMP location
String line = null; 
BufferedReader skipLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
while ((line = skipLine.readLine()) != null) {
             line = line + "\n";
             writer.write(line);
}
```

Comment: What's the encoding of the uploaded CSV file? Note that on Windows the file might be encoded in cp1252. Generally the problem is that if you accept any user supplied CSV you'll have to know (or guess) the encoding since it depends on what the users are using. Normally you'd like the files to be UTF-8 encoded but unfortunately you can't rely on that.

Comment: Check the **bytes** you receive when the message is sent from linux and from windows. When you have found the difference try find out which encoding is working and always use that.

Comment: @Thomas: The encoding of the CSV file we used is cp1252. But still we are unable to read the Euro symbols from CSV. However, the encoding for other characters are also lost.

Comment: What encoding was the file _uploaded_ as?  Maybe you need to read this from the `FormDataBodyPart` using `FormDataBodyPart.getMediaType()`. For text/plain media type, the encoding can sometimes be specified with something like `text/plain; charset=UTF-8` which you can read programiatically using `mediaType.getParameters().get(MediaType.CHARSET_PARAMETER)`.  Right now you are assuming a particular encoding when writing which may not be correct.